# Public accommodation arbitrary refusal of service example?

Tags: arbitration, wisconsin, notice

This is maybe nothing but stupidity on my end...but;
Fitness center with tanning in Wisconsin.
Went to tan as have done before, worker asked if I had protective eyewear  (law to have in Wi) to which I replied yes—as in past practice—this time she said show it to her. Which I said what? Why? She replied it’s the law (it’s not—to which I also replied, it’s that I have and use, which I told you I do, not that I’m required to show you) Okay, I realize I could have just showed her, but I felt my word was good, unsure why it wouldn’t be, was unaware of this new “law” (it’s not)....asked to speak with manager, he too refused service-I asked when, where, why—it did not go well...so, were they right in denying my service even though I would not show them the googles even though I verbally indicated I had them etc.

Answer (score 4):

It is entirely legal to discriminate on arbitrary grounds. What is not legal is to discriminate on the basis of a protected category, for example race. The law say that you cannot favor or disfavor a customer because of their race. Federal law specifically prohibits discrimination on the basis of race, color, religion, or national origin, but not age or gender (disability is more complicated). Moreover, the grounds are not arbitrary. The establishment is at legal risk if a customer does not wear eye-protection, and you have no right to compel them to assume that risk: it's a perfectly normal business decision. [The law states](https://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/statutes/statutes/463/25/6) that "Customers are not allowed to use a tanning device unless the customer uses protective eyewear", and verifying that you have such eyewear is the minimal way of assuring compliance with the law.

Comment: Actually, further up on that link, the law requires the owner to provide such eyewear.